# JWT token in String or JSON format in Flask app

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pyjwt

So I am having trouble with JWT tokens. After my token runs trough function to decode it it is supposed to return some data from SQLAlchemy database. But instead of data I get `<__main__.SortRules object at 0x1074befe0>` if I return it as string or `TypeError: Object of type SortRules is not JSON serializable` if I just return it. I need to get this as some readable format *string* or *JSON*.

`current_user = create_user in token_required` - stores user ID which is taken from database

Decoder fnction for JWT:

```py
def token_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        token = None
        local_session = Session(bind=engine)
        
        data = jwt.decode(token, app.config['SECRET_KEY'], algorithms=['HS256'])
        create_users = local_session.query(User).filter_by(public_id=data['public_id']).first()

        return f(create_users, *args, **kwargs)
    
    return decorated
```

Function where i call JWT token:

```py
class SortRules(Resource):
    @token_required
    def post(self, current_user):

        return current_user

        OR

        return str(current_user)

api.add_resource(SortRules, '/v1/postRule')
```

I tried some JSON decoders I found here but it didn't help.
Tried this one for example but it only returned empty JSON:

```py
class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
        def default(self, o):
            return o.__dict__ 

MyEncoder().encode(current_user)
json.dumps(current_user ,cls=MyEncoder)
```

Also tried `current_user.decode('utf-8')` throws `AttributeError: 'SortRules' object has no attribute 'decode'`

So is there any way I can get what I need from JWT token in string or JSON format ?

Comment: You've provided a confusing pile of code here with no clear indication of how you're getting that error.  What is calling what here?  How does `SortRules` get invoked?

Comment: `SortRules` is just creating endpoint that is called with some API request.

Comment: OK, but you said "Also tried .decode('utf-8')".  WHERE did you try that?  On what object?

Comment: I didnt see the code that create the SortRules object anywhere in the post, where and how did you create the SortRules object?

Comment: @TimRoberts it was used on ‘current_user’. Its updated already

Comment: @LLL ‘SortRules’ is just creating endpoint, it works fine bur I will add it so you can see.